# Complex Meta Query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have a meta_query which works fine like:

```
$meta_query_args = array(
array(
    'key'     => 'price',
    'value'   => 145,
    'compare' => '='
)
);
```

I know this returns the `post_id` field(?)

How can I return a `meta_value` instead of a `meta_key` of the same `post_id` sa the meta query above.

Let's say the query above returned `post_id 99`, how can I get the `meta_value` of `meta_key 'project'` with the `post_id 99`. Can I combine it with the query I have above?

So instead of the query returning 99, it should return the `meta_value` instead

Thanks

Comment: Just to make answering clearer, what's happening with `$meta_query_args`? Are you putting it into `WP_Query` or `get_posts()`?

Comment: I'm putting it into WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

```
get_post_meta( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )
```

Go through https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/